# Allow user to register to Openfire server using OpenLDAP

Tags: xmpp, openfire, openldap

I've successfully setup Openfire 3.7.1 communicating with OpenLDAP 2.4.28 on ArchLinux 2011.08.19. I want XMPP users to be able to register and the registration should be accepted by OpenLDAP server and (because it's LDAP) the registration should be global. So if a user comes in, registers through XMPP, he should be able to login on the web or access his public FTP. The same with web registration. How can I accomplish this? my current slapd config is this:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema

pidfile         /run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile        /run/openldap/slapd.args

    access to dn.subtree="dc=domain,dc=tld" attrs=uid,userPassword
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by * none

    access to dn.children="dc=domain,dc=tld" attrs=cn,gn,sn,displayName,mail,mobile,homePhone,homePostalAddress,telephoneNumber
        by self write
        by * read

    access to dn.subtree="dc=domain,dc=tld"
        by * read

    access to * by * read

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=domain,dc=tld"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=tld"
rootpw          {SSHA}secret
directory       /var/lib/openldap/openldap-data
index   objectClass     eq
```

Comment: Why did you add the `active-directory` tag?

Comment: This is a non programming question, you should have beter audience in ServerFault

Comment: Nice question, I'd really like to see what you achieved. But this question belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Sorry for that. Can someone move it for me, please? Anyway. I've just switched off LDAP and use local DB instead. I'll not use LDAP because it sucks (read-only access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to actually create the user information on the OpenLDAP server following their registration on the OpenFire server. The connection from the OpenFire server to the LDAP database is considered 'read-only'.

If you want to have the data globally available following registration, you will need to insert the user into the LDAP server. It is trivial to insert user information into an OpenLDAP server, but I think to add user information to an Active-Directory server requires specific tools (I've never used anything other than windows client-side tools to perform this activity against a windows server).

I don't know enough about the OpenFire system to know how you would accomplish this.